# About subquery in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question. I want to know when I run sub query several times to get the same value then subquery executes each time or not.

For example: I have this query:

```
SELECT [, columns] 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE id >= (SELECT MAX(SomeTableId) FROM OtherTable)
```

Does the subquery execute several times, or not?

Comment: It will not. You should be able to determine that from the execution plan IIRC. It wouldn't be logical to execute it each time either.

Comment: As @TT mentioned the execution plan will show how the query is executed. You can run the query from an SSMS query window with the include actual plan option to see the plan. I would expect the max value to be retrieved once during query execution because the subquery is not correlated. I recommend one always specify table aliases and qualify column names in multi-table queries to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.  For your example, SQL Server is smart enough to run the query only once.  That is an optimization.

Often, such constructs are moved into the `FROM` clause so single-execution is more obvious:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM SomeTable s JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(SomeTableId) as max_SomeTableId
      FROM OtherTable
     ) o
     ON s.id >= max_SomeTableId;
```

If your query has a correlation clause (usually a `where` or `having` clause that references the outer query), then it *may* be run more than once.

I say "may" because the actual execution plan could look nothing like your original query.  SQL is a declarative language where the "query" actually expresses what the result set should look like.  The optimizer can choose whatever method it like to arrive at the declared result set.